# when to release NSDictionary instance and all its values?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary that's created and initialized in following ways

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:N];
for (int index = 0; index < N; index++) {
    MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    ...
    [dict setObject:obj forKey:index];
}
```

So the questions are
 1. should the MyObject instances be created as autorelease?
 2. once I need to release the NSDictionary instance, should I also release all the MyObject instances (if they are not created as autorelease)

Comment: If you want a collection of objects by ordered numeric indexes, you want [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) or [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/), not NSDictionary. NSDictionary won't preserve the sequence of indexes if you remove an item; all the remaining entries will remain unchanged, leaving a gap in the index sequence. Also (and relatedly), keys in a dictionary must be copyable objects (such as strings), not `int`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly release MyObject instances after calling setObject since they will be retained at that point. You can autorelease MyObject instances, but explicit releasing will be more efficient.  Releasing the NSDictionary instance will release MyObject instances.